# Unable to dual boot after installing win10 along with pre installed ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi, dualboot, easybcd

**Problem**
I wanted to dual boot my existing ubuntu 20.04 system with windows 10.
But after installing win10, I installed easy bcd to dual boot. Shockingly it displayed in linux option that win10 doesn't support efi system.

*Hence, I'm not able to switch in ubuntu again as  after restarting windows 10 is loading automatically.*

**

> So, how can I dual boot system or if not possible how can I switch to
> old ubuntu as I installed windows 10 in separated partition without
> loosing any data?

**
I've searched many tutorials but mostly ended up with converting uefi to legacy which I don't want to change.

Thanks in advance!

Now I'm able to return to ubuntu again as I reckon after installing windows I installed grub2. So, I uninstalled it and after restarting I can  select ubuntu from boot option.
But how can I get automatically dual boot option instead of clicking on F9 while restarting?
Both ubuntu and windows is in UEFI mode.

Comment: You probably installed Windows with CPM enabled resulting in it not being installed on GPT.  Can you confirm? Windows absolutely supports EFI provided it’s installed in UEFI only mode on a GPT disk

Comment: EasyBCD is what doesn't support UEFI. Windows 10 does and **prefers UEFI**, mandatory for any preinstalled Windows since Windows 8 in 2012. You need to learn about the UEFI mode, its requirements and how to manage boot in a multi OS scenario. Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @Ramhound from boot option both windows and ubuntu is showing in UEFI mode